# No Jade, como posso suprimir o erro se uma variável não existir?

Tags: node.js, express.js, jade

Estou tentando criar um formulário para criar um usuário, mas uso o mesmo formulário para editar.
Quando eu tento criar um novo usuário o app me mostra um erro porque nos campos do formulário ele tenta pegar informações de um usuário que, obviamente, não existe porque estou criando e não editando informações.

No PHP usamos `@$user->name` para suprimir erros, mas como fazer isso com jade?

```
input.form-control(name='name',value=user.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- if (typeof(user.name) !== 'undefined'){
  //-aqui você coloca o seu código
-}
```

Acho que isso resolve.